# @angular @ngrx/effects HTTP Request Keeps Canceling and Retrying

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a very simple effect in place that makes a http request and dispatches an action when it's complete.

The HTTP request is constantly canceled and remade over and over.

[image]

Originally I thought it was switchMap that was causing the issue (canceling the observable) so I tried using mergeMap (same result).

Below is my code for the effect.

```html
signIn$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ACTIONS.AUTH.SIGN_IN)
  .map(toPayload)
  .map(payload => toInput(payload))
  .switchMap(input => this.http
      .post<Output>(`${GLOBALS.endpoint}/auth/authenticate`, input)
      .map(output => ({ type: ACTIONS.APP.PUSH_NOTIFICATION, payload: "test" }))
      .catch(error => of(createAction(ACTIONS.APP.LOG_EXCEPTION, error)))
  );
```

The above code compiles without errors and works as expected, except the fact that it keeps canceling and remaking the http request.

I don't know if it matters but I am using the HttpClient (@angular/common/http), not @angular/http.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The issue here ended up being an ng HTTP interceptor that I wrote. I was binding to my store observable to retrieve it's state for custom HTTP headers. There was an issue in the way I was binding to that observable that was causing the http requests to send multiple times with store updates (triggered by the effects). The error was not in the effects code at all. Just for future readers of this post :)

Answer (score 6):

"switchMap" has his own "unsubscribe" mechanism
that cancel the api requests,

using "flatMap" (or mergeMap) instead should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are sending the same request multiple times within a short time frame. Try to limit the request to only when the token changed. Below might work:

```
signIn$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(ACTIONS.AUTH.SIGN_IN)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map(payload => toInput(payload))
  .switchMap(input => this.http
      .post<Output>(`${GLOBALS.endpoint}/auth/authenticate`, input)
      .map(output => ({ type: ACTIONS.APP.PUSH_NOTIFICATION, payload: "test" }))
      .catch(error => of(createAction(ACTIONS.APP.LOG_EXCEPTION, error)))
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried that and I am still having the same issue. If I use a .do(console.log) instead of the distinctUntilChanged(), it is only firing once (if that helps). The part that appears to fire multiple times is the .switchMap. Any .do logs under or after there will fire repeatedly.

Comment: Try `distinctUntilKeyChanged('email')` or something like that